# Creating a class to store threads and calling them

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class client {
private:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::atomic<bool> running;

    void main() {
        while(running) {
            std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void render() {
        while(running) {
            std::cout << "render" << std::endl;
        }
    }
public:
    client() {
        running = true;

        threads.push_back(std::thread(&client::main, this));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&client::render, this));
    }

    ~client() {
        running = false;
        for(auto& th : threads) th.join();
    };
};

int main() {
    client c;

    std::string inputString;
    getline(std::cin, inputString);

    return 0;
}
```

---

(Note: code has been changed since question was written)

What I am trying to do is create a class that holds threads for the main loop(of the class), rendering, and a couple other things.  However I cannot get this simplified version to work.  I have tried using mutex to lock and unlock the threads, but didn't seem to help any.  I do not know why it is not working, but I suspect that it is a result of the use of `this` in `threads.push_back(std::thread(this->main, this));`.

The current structure of the code doesn't have to remain... The only requirement is that uses one of it's own member functions as a thread (and that, that thread is stored in the class).  I am not sure if this requires two classes or if my attempt to do it in one class was the correct approach.  I have seen many examples of creating an object, and then calling a member that creates threads.  I am trying to avoid this and instead create the threads within the constructor.

Comment: What are you running this on? With GCC, I can't even compile the program, it complaining about passing `this->main` and `this->render` to the `thread` constructor as being *"invalid use of non-static member function"*.

Comment: @Dolda2000 MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you do not wait for the threads to end.  In `main` you create `c`.  This then spawns the threads.  The next thing to happen is to return which destroys `c`.  When `c` is destroyed it destroys its members.  Now when a thread is destroyed if it has not been joined or detached then [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is called and the program ends

What you need to do is in the destructor, set `running` to `false` and then call `join` on both the threads.  This will stop the loop in each thread and allow `c` to be destructed correctly.

Doing this however brings up another issue.  `running` is not an atomic variable so writing to it while threads are reading it is undefined behavior.  We can fin that though by changing running to a `std::atomic<bool>` which provides synchronization.

I also had to make a change to the thread construction.  When you want to use a member function the syntax should be

```
std::thread(&class_name::function_name, pointer_to_instance_of_class_name, function_parameters)
```

so in this case it would be

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(&client::main, this));
threads.push_back(std::thread(&client::render, this));
```

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly and everything works like a charm, however the placeholder variable `running` is actually a bool returned by a function.  How would I go about making sure that this is thread safe?